# Adding new Object in Spin Object Camunda

Tags: java, bpmn, camunda

I am creating a new variable in Camunda

```
 var userData = [
    {
        name: "rajesh",
        age: 40
    },{
        name: "aara",
        age: 4
    }
]

execution.setVariable("userData", S(JSON.stringify(userData)).mapTo("java.util.ArrayList"));
```

I want to add a new Object into it, how can i do that?

```
newUser = {
name: "vijay",
age: 35
};

userData.add(JSON.stringify(newUser))    
print(userData)
```

This gives me output like this : `[{"name":"rajesh","age":40},{"name":"aara","age":4},"{\"name\":\"vijay\",\"age\":35}"]`

Please help

Answer (score 0):

Did you see the docuemntataion for it
https://docs.camunda.org/manual/latest/user-guide/data-formats/json/
?
Waht is unclear / failing?

Answer (score 0):

Thouth it is an old question, I faced the same one recently. Here is the solution.

1. let the variable be `org.camunda.spin.impl.json.jackson.JacksonJsonNode` but `java.util.ArrayList`, therefore `.mapTo("java.util.ArrayList")` is unnecessory;
2. Use `JacksonJsonNode#append` method to add a new element, thus the code may look like

```js
var newUser = {
name: "vijay",
age: 35
};

S(userData).append(S(JSON.stringify(newUser)));
```